# TextBox in UserControl not rendering correctly

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, textbox

Suppose I have a UserControl `Editor` it has a `TextBox`. It also have a property `Content`. Here I just set the text content to a static value "Hey"

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Editor" ...>
    <TextBox Text="Hey" />
    <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" />-->
</UserControl>
```

Then I have a Window to display all this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1" ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:Editor Content="Heya" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When I run it, I get

[image]

Its not even a TextBox? And why do I get the content set in `<local:Editor />`. I tried Clean & Rebuild solution and I still get this wierd thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Simple enough. A `UserControl` is just a `ContentControl` actually, so it has a dependency property named `Content`. When you set this property, you set the whole content of your `ContentControl`. The Content property is the default one (have a look at default properties for WPF at MSDN).

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Editor" ...>

    <!-- Here, you set the Content property (because it is
    the default one) of the UserControl as a TextBox with 
    the text "Hey". -->

    <TextBox Text="Hey" />
</UserControl>
```

Compare above and below codes:

```
<!-- Here, the Content property is explicitly set. -->
<local:Editor Content="Heya" />
```

In both cases, you define the Content property with different content...

---

## Solution

To solve your issue, define a custom `DependencyProperty` in `Editor` named `TextContent` for instance, and do the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Editor" ...>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</UserControl>
```

And:

```
<local:Editor TextContent="Heya" />
```

Comment: Ah... Finally, after so long of scratching my head!